# Assembly programming is not a valid option when writing code for several type of microprocessors?

Tags: assembly

Is that true that assembly programming is not a valid option when writing code for several types of microprocessors?

Since it is an very elementary programming language, I would say it is relevant to use assembly for different type of microprocessors. Is that true?

Comment: Sure it's a valid option, but you have to write your code separately for each different ISA, and you usually want a generic fallback in a portable language like C.  e.g. look at https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn - GMP has hand-written asm versions of some functions for many different ISAs.

Comment: This is nonsense. Where did you read this?

Comment: If creating an operating system with versions for multiple-processors (such as Windows NT 4.0), some assembly language is required for things like context switch, interrupt handling, which would be different for each processor type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are and will continue to be competing, incompatible, instruction sets that power our lives.  The problem of programming languages has existed for a long time now, since almost the beginning of the modern looking instruction based, binary based processors.  C and Unix evolved from this problem.  You had the government funded darpanet/arpanet where digital communication was being formed at least in the USA, but your different universities had different equipment for various reasons, cost, funding, etc.

So while each could sit down and write the software in whatever language to try to conform to some communication protocol, that code was not portable, university X could share their code but if you didn't buy the same machine there wasn't much you could do with it.  Understanding this was our infancy both the hardware and the languages and the processors and the programmers.   But eventually the hardware was good enough and the programmers good enough to implement the notion of an abstraction.  A generic programming language that could be "compiled" into the native languages of the hardware, you didn't need to port every program you only need to build the compiler then in theory each new program you simply compiled.  And take it to the next step of an operating system with its abstractions so that the programs could use a common set of APIs.

At the end of the day though each processor has an instruction set that is incompatible with other processors, even within a family you have x86 code that is incompatible with other x86's.  ARM with ARM, as well as the natural ARM with x86.   If you want the code to run it has to be boiled down into machine code, you cannot get around that.  Each processor has an assembly language and tools otherwise how did they create and test that processor in the first place.  Does that mean that you have to use that language no, does that mean you can, absolutely if you choose.  Can you outperform a compiler, most people cannot but some can and can consistently but it is more lines of code so it just takes longer, it is a balance of time and effort vs the reward you get if any.

Assembly language is specific to the tool not the target, there are many incompatible x86 assembly languages capable of generating the same machine code just like there are incompatible ARM assembly languages and MIPS and so on.  So even for the same chip on the same board there can and often does exist incompatible assembly languages much less if the logic is incompatible.  We do not quite understand your question as written, but if you are asking if you can write assembly language code and use it on different processors, that is not assumed to be true.

Then you have the situation not just mips and arm x86 as well, but more with arm and mips and other purchased IP cores where the chip company buys a processor core a memory controller, a usb controller, etc and glues it into a chip.  The processor core is just one part of it that they purchase and glue in.  x86 and the pc due to history and a major reason for the success is reverse compatibility so that means even today you can find a serial port (if you have one, servers still come with them) that you can reach through the same I/O space addressing from a programmers perspective (Even if that is virtualized in hardware it is still not just a software abstraction that makes it work).

The ARM and MIPS and other worlds do not have this feature/problem.  Take a Raspberry Pi and a beaglebone and even if they happen to use cores with the same instruction set, pretty close to zero of the code will port, because the instruction set is only a tiny part of it most of your code is not related to the instruction set, or at least code that you might consider writing in assembly language.  Same core but the uarts, the memory controllers, etc are both incompatible logic and are at different addresses, so you have to write code for each usually, in whatever language you choose.

Not a complete example but assembly language (well machine code) is similar to the alphabet or a core language like English.  Most of the population of the earth does not speak/read English, but because a math book is written in English does that mean that math is different in different countries?  No, the math is the same the delivery system to the human is through different, incompatible, languages.  There are a number of incompatible languages that share the same alphabet, they are still incompatible though (two chips that have the same ARM core but the code, high or low level will not work)  You take the high level concept and then you implement it in a specific language that is compatible with the user be it a human or a microprocessor.

Creating a universal assembly language makes no sense, especially now that we have so many languages, just pick one of a few that are powerful enough to do the job and can be compiled into a specific target.  And have the option of porting that code or portions of it to another target with a different processor.

So you can use assembly language for many/every different type of processor? Yes.  That does not even imply that the code is portable or looks remotely the same from one processor to another.  It is a perfectly valid option, you just have to write the code for each processor separately.

Is it very elementary?  Yes.  Does that mean that you can use it for many different types of processors?  Yes the term assembly language applies to many different processors, but that does not mean the exact code you write will work, expect to write the code again and again for each processor.

Just ask a compiler (or a set of them)

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x&1);
}

fun:
    and r0, r0, #1
    bx  lr

fun:
    and w0, w0, 1
    ret

fun:
    jr  $31
    andi    $2,$4,0x1

fun:
    ldi.l   $r1, 1
    and $r0, $r1
    ret

fun:
    mov 02(sp),r0
    bic $-02,r0
    rts pc

fun:
    andi    a0,a0,1
    ret
```

And that is just one toolchain that feeds into an assembler that has some common language qualities among targets.

Not uncommon to see this for one tool

```
fun:
    jr  $31
    andi    $2,$4,0x1
```

and this for another

```
fun
    jr  r31
    andi    r2,r4,#0x1
```

at least that kind of thing where labels do or do not have a colon.  How the registers are described, how constants are marked 0x1 or #0x1 or 1h or $1 are all well known, incompatible, forms for that value depending on tool and target.